# How to make future projections without data ? (R)

Tags: r

So I have a trained model using historical data. The dependent variable is ave_premium. A snip of the data is per below and goes up to year 2020 month 12. I'm trying to make future projections for year 2021. I'm able to provide Year, Month, categoryCategory.B, categoryCategory.C and the rest will be missing values.

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wQ81.png)

My approach is predicting the value for remaining variables (leaving ave_premium out), and then use the predicted data of 2021 to predict ave_premium for 2021. In the example below, to predict the values for quota in 2021, I removed all other variables and train the model with Year, Month, categoryCategory.B, categoryCategory.C and ave_quota (2010-2020). I then create a subset of empty 2021, containing only Year, Month, categoryCategory.B, categoryCategory.C and predict using the trained model above.

```
dmy2 <- dummyVars('~.', data = coeproj, fullRank = T)
dmy_transformed2 <- data.frame(predict(dmy2, newdata = coeproj))
glimpse(dmy_transformed2)
dmy_transformed2_quota <- subset(dmy_transformed2,(Year<2021) )

#predict 2021 quota
ranger_quota <- ranger(ave_quota ~Year+categoryCategory.B+ categoryCategory.C, data = dmy_transformed2_quota,
                       min.node.size = 2, sample.fraction = 0.859,importance = 'impurity')
dmy_transformed2_quotaproj <- subset(dmy_transformed2,  (Year>2020) )
dmy_transformed2_quotaproj <- subset(dmy_transformed2_quotaproj,select = -c(ave_bidsreceived,reg_car,dereg_car,cum_yoygrowth,primelendingrate,X5.Year,X10.Year,ave_premium,cum_index))
pred_quota<- predict(ranger_quota, data=dmy_transformed2_quotaproj)
pred_quota_pred <- round(pred_quota$predictions,0)

dmy_transformed2_quotaproj$ave_quota <- pred_quota_pred
```

Here's the output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnOTI.png)

As you can see, the numbers are just interchanging between 1109, 1032 and 445 which i supposed was due to the category B and C.

What's a better way to do this? I need to do for the rest of the variables as well.

Here's my dataset using dput

```
structure(list(Year = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021), Month = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 
7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 
11, 11, 12, 12, 12), categoryCategory.B = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), categoryCategory.C = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1), ave_quota = c(1034, 1017, 325, 982, 986, 333, 
980, 990, 382, 1296, 1315, 489, 1028, 928, 358, 1034, 908, 352, 
914, 799, 316, 970, 1010, 370, 974, 1022, 368, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ave_bidsreceived = c(1420, 1193, 
480, 1384, 1316, 532, 1428, 1356, 606, 2773, 2828, 812, 2073, 
1856, 622, 1638, 1606, 558, 1298, 1245, 562, 1312, 1487, 578, 
1512, 1672, 620, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), ave_premium = c(35165, 37407, 24701.5, 31504.5, 31889.5, 25007, 
31954.5, 31406.5, 23102, 33109.5, 35445, 24195, 34355, 37952, 
24553, 38135, 41249.5, 27616.5, 36934, 40840, 33433.5, 36840, 
40050.5, 30918, 40635, 47156, 34045, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), reg_car = c(2160, 2861, 822, 2028, 2630, 
733, 2250, 2732, 993, 1909, 2912, 884, 2277, 2897, 1091, 1978, 
2578, 1219, 2091, 2650, 993, 1819, 2840, 858, 1291, 2614, 978, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), dereg_car = c(2239, 
2111, 787, 1778, 2030, 914, 2397, 2279, 1407, 1697, 1762, 914, 
1750, 1790, 1095, 1537, 1705, 930, 1518, 1659, 805, 1506, 1582, 
683, 1425, 1590, 699, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), cum_index = c(2.773472222, 5.546944444, 8.320416667, 11.09388889, 
13.86736111, 16.64083333, 19.41430556, 22.18777778, 24.96125, 
52.69597222, 55.46944444, 58.24291667, 61.01638889, 63.78986111, 
66.56333333, 69.33680556, 72.11027778, 74.88375, 77.65722222, 
80.43069444, 83.20416667, 85.97763889, 88.75111111, 91.52458333, 
94.29805556, 97.07152778, 99.845, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), cum_yoygrowth = c(-0.005555556, -0.011111111, 
-0.016666667, -0.022222222, -0.027777778, -0.033333333, -0.038888889, 
-0.044444444, -0.05, -0.105555556, -0.111111111, -0.116666667, 
-0.122222222, -0.127777778, -0.133333333, -0.138888889, -0.144444444, 
-0.15, -0.155555556, -0.161111111, -0.166666667, -0.172222222, 
-0.177777778, -0.183333333, -0.188888889, -0.194444444, -0.2, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), primelendingrate = c(5.25, 
5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 
5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 
5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), X5.Year = c(1159, 289, 491, 532, 150, 425, 574, 215, 807, 
461, 159, 563, 661, 194, 532, 571, 151, 851, 336, 67, 694, 219, 
48, 371, 334, 92, 569, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), X10.Year = c(443, 567, 97, 193, 436, 64, 262, 738, 79, 257, 
816, 90, 419, 1725, 75, 403, 1064, 171, 208, 453, 151, 177, 354, 
52, 334, 942, 69, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
)), row.names = c("361", "362", "363", "364", "365", "366", "367", 
"368", "369", "370", "371", "372", "373", "374", "375", "376", 
"377", "378", "379", "380", "381", "382", "383", "384", "385", 
"386", "387", "388", "389", "390", "391", "392", "393", "394", 
"395", "396", "397", "398", "399", "400", "401", "402", "403", 
"404", "405", "406", "407", "408", "409", "410", "411", "412", 
"413", "414"), class = "data.frame")
```

I need a away to predict 2021 data to predict ave_premium using the trained model.

Comment: It's really hard to help with this when your input and output are images. Try to make the post reproducible so people can help you more easily. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example For R stuff, see the package `reprex` for helping you to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily impute the missing value for the year 2021 with the `caret` package. `caret` provide the `preProcess` function that can be used to [impute](https://topepo.github.io/caret/pre-processing.html#imputation) data sets based only on information in the training set. In particular, with the `method` argument you can choose between imputing with the K-nn method, with bagged trees, or simply by using the median value of the predictors.
Here I put an example of `caret` workflow with your data.

```
library(caret)
#impute the missing value with bagged trees method excluding the outcome variable
pp <- preProcess(df[,-7],method="bagImpute")
df.pp <- predict(pp,df[,-7])
df.pp$ave_premium <- df$ave_premium

#split dataset according to the year
training <- df.pp[df.pp$Year<2021,]
df.2021 <- df.pp[df.pp$Year>2020,]
#set the resampling method for cross-validation (here 5-fold cross validation)
control <- trainControl(method = "cv",number=5)
#set the tuning grid (the values of parameters that will be tried in the model fitting, during the cross-validation)
grid <- expand.grid(mtry=2:(ncol(training)-1),splitrule="extratrees",min.node.size=seq(0.1,1,0.1))
#fit the model using "ranger"
fit <- train(ave_premium~.,data=training,method="ranger",trControl=control,tuneGrid=grid)
#calculate the RMSE% from cross-validation
rmse_perc <- min(fit$results$RMSE)/mean(training$ave_premium)*100

#predict ave_premium for 2021
df.2021$ave_premium <- predict(fit,df.2021[,-14])

#merge the 2 data.frame
df.pred <- rbind(training,df.2021)
```

for more info on `caret` you can see [here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html). It is very well documented.